# windows-phone-7.1 quits application right after a set

Tags: c#, set, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I am trying to make a application and i am just figuring out how everything works on a windows phone.

In the Windows Phone emulator i try to run my application but it just returns back to the previous screen without any errors. (The compiler doesn't give me any errors either.)

Even if i dont put anything besides this.voice = value it still doesn't work.

here is the code where the error occurs :

```
   // volume of the voice of the commentator;
   public int voice { 
        get 
        { 
            return voice; 
        }
        set 
        {
            settings["voice"] = this.voice = (int)value;  // right here it just stops.
        }
```

The code where i call this function is :

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       // example :: ExceptionHandler.newException("er is geen exception");

        Option option = new Option();
        option.backgroundMusic = 22; // here
        option.voice = 32; // here

    }
}
```

And for a total picture :

Mainpage :

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       // example :: ExceptionHandler.newException("er is geen exception");

        Option option = new Option();
        option.backgroundMusic = 22;
        option.voice = 32;

    }
}
```

Class Option :

```
    public class Option
    {
    // isolated storage settings connection.
    private static IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings; 

    // volume of the backgroundMusic;
    public int backgroundMusic { 
        get 
        { 
            return backgroundMusic; 
        } 
        set 
        {
            settings["backgroundMusic"] = this.backgroundMusic = (int)value; 
        } 
    } 

    // volume of the voice of the commentator;
    public int voice { 
        get 
        { 
            return voice; 
        }
        set 
        {
            settings["voice"] = this.voice = (int)value; 
        } 
    }





    public Option()
    {
        // If the keys doesn't exists
        if (!settings.Contains("backgroundMusic") && !settings.Contains("voice"))
        {

            // Create the settings.
            settings.Add("backgroundMusic", (int)50 );
            settings.Add("voice", (int)50);
        }
        // If the key exists, retrieve the value and set the properties of backgroundMusic and voice
        else
        {
            this.backgroundMusic = (int)settings["backgroundMusic"];
            this.voice = (int)settings["voice"];
        }
    }
}
```

edit :

I am open for suggestions if i did something else wrong or something could be better please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop? `this.voice = value` fires the set again, what makes a loop.

You have to declare another field and use it as a value store:

```
private int _voice;
public int voice
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return _voice; 
    }
    set 
    {
        settings["voice"] = _voice = (int)value; 
    } 
}
```

You have to do the same with the second property as well.